# Goroutines got hung up after a while

Tags: go, goroutine

I am writing a program to check my SOCKS5 proxies. My way is to iterate over each element in the proxy array and create one goroutine for each proxy, and the program was ran perfectly, but, after a while (About 10 seconds after run the program), my program will be stopped for a long time and does nothing, even though it hasn't finished checking the list of proxies. How must I do now? This is my code:

```golang
func checkProxy(proxyAddress string, timeout time.Duration, sw *sync.WaitGroup, sm *sync.Mutex) {
    retry := 0
    headers := []byte("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + PROXY_JUDGE_HOST + "\r\n\r\n")
    for {
        if retry == 3 {
            break
        }
        conn, err := SocksClient(proxyAddress, PROXY_JUDGE_ADDRESS, timeout)
        if err != nil {
            retry++
            return
        }
        func(netConn net.Conn) {
            defer netConn.Close()
            if _, err = conn.Write(headers); err != nil {
                return
            }
        }(conn)
        break
    }
    fmt.Println("Found GOOD proxies: " + proxyAddress)
    sm.Lock()
    liveProxies = append(liveProxies, proxyAddress)
    sm.Unlock()
    sw.Done()
}

func main() {
    var sw sync.WaitGroup
    var sm sync.Mutex
    totalProxies = readFile("socks5.txt")
    for i := 0; i < len(totalProxies); i++ {
        sw.Add(1)
        go checkProxy(totalProxies[i], 1*time.Second, &sw, &sm)
    }
    sw.Wait()
    // Code to add proxies list to the new file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is one path where your function returns before decrementing the counter on the sync.WaitGroup:

```golang
func checkProxy(....) {
    for {
    ....
        if err != nil {
            retry++
            return
        }
    }

}
```

I guess you meant to add a `continue` there instead. If there is an error, the `sw.Done()` call will never be executed as the function returns before.

As a best practice make sure you defer your `sw.Done` call so it is called on any exit path.

```golang
func checkProxy(..., sw *sync.WaitGroup, ...) {
   defer sw.Done() // decrement once goroutine is done.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. if retry == 3 must return
2. if error caught in call `SocksClient` should `retry++` and `continue` to retry

> note : I haven't tried this code bcz I don't have the file

```golang
func checkProxy(proxyAddress string, timeout time.Duration, sw *sync.WaitGroup, sm *sync.Mutex) {
    defer sw.Done()
    retry := 0
    headers := []byte("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + PROXY_JUDGE_HOST + "\r\n\r\n")
    for {
        if retry == 3 {
            return // not break
        }
        conn, err := SocksClient(proxyAddress, PROXY_JUDGE_ADDRESS, timeout)
        if err != nil {
            retry++
            time.Sleep(10*time.Second) // retry in 10 seconds
            continue // not return
        }
        func(netConn net.Conn) {
            defer netConn.Close()
            if _, err = conn.Write(headers); err != nil {
                return
            }
        }(conn)
        break
    }
    fmt.Println("Found GOOD proxies: " + proxyAddress)
    sm.Lock()
    liveProxies = append(liveProxies, proxyAddress)
    sm.Unlock()
}
```

Comment: I have changed the 1 and 2 but the program still stuck

Comment: Are you have change the location of `defer sw.Done()` ?

Comment: Yes I did it too